# The existence of convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $A$ denote the set of all strictly increasing sequences in $\mathbb{N}$, i.e. sequences $(n_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $n_1 < n_2 < n_3 < ···$ Consider the sequence  $(f_n)$ in $[−1,1]^A$ given by

\begin{equation}
  f_n((n_k))=\begin{cases}
    (-1)^k, & \text{if $n=n_k$ for some $k$}.\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}

My question is that is there any convergent subsequence of $(f_n)$ in product topology? Thanks!

Comment: Convergent in what topology?

Comment: emmm...I think convergent in product topology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ that converges in the product topology. Let $a$ be the strictly increasing sequence $(n_k)_{k=1}^\infty$(we have $a_k=n_k$ in fact; we only introduce the notation $a$ to avoid confusion). Then $f_{n_k}(a)=(-1)^k$ which has not limit. Consequently there is no convergent subsequence of $f_n$.

Comment: silly me! Thanks!